# SSL options in gocql

Tags: ssl, go, cassandra, cqlsh

In my Cassandra config I have enabled user authentication and connect with cqlsh over ssl.
I'm having trouble implementing the same with gocql, following is my code:

```
cluster := gocql.NewCluster("127.0.0.1")
cluster.Authenticator = gocql.PasswordAuthenticator{
    Username: "myuser",
    Password: "mypassword",
}
cluster.SslOpts = &gocql.SslOptions {
    CertPath: "/path/to/cert.pem",
}
```

When I try to connect I get following error:

```
 gocql: unable to create session: connectionpool: unable to load X509 key pair: open : no such file or directory
```

In python I can do this with something like:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
USER = 'username'
PASS = 'password'
ssl_opts = {'ca_certs': '/path/to/cert.pem',
        'ssl_version': PROTOCOL_TLSv1
}
credentials = PlainTextAuthProvider(username = USER, password = PASS)
# define host, port, cqlsh protocaol version
cluster = Cluster(contact_points= HOST, protocol_version= CQLSH_PROTOCOL_VERSION, auth_provider = credentials, port = CASSANDRA_PORT)
```

I checked the gocql and TLS documentation [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/gocql/gocql#SslOptions) and [here](https://godoc.org/crypto/tls#Config) but I'm unsure about how to set ssl options.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding a cert without a private key, which is where the "no such file or directory" error is coming from.

Your python code is adding a CA; you should do the same with the Go code:

```
gocql.SslOptions {
    CaPath: "/path/to/cert.pem",
}
```