# How to connect to yugabyte instance from app using certificates? Able to connect via ycqlsh but not from golang application

Tags: go, cqlsh, yugabytedb

I was able to connect to the yugabyte cassandra instance through ycqlsh with the given certificates.

`ycqlsh <host> --ssl`

Have exported the env var SSL_CERTFILE. This works but from the golang application passing the same certificates gives me an error.

```
func getYugaByteConnection() *gocql.Session {
    cluster := gocql.NewCluster("<host>")
    cluster.Timeout = 12 * time.Second
    //cluster.ConnectTimeout = 12 * time.Second
    cluster.SslOpts = &gocql.SslOptions{
        EnableHostVerification: true,
        CertPath:               "path/to/cert.pem",
    }

    session, err := cluster.CreateSession()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    return session
}
```

This gives me an error saying

```
gocql: unable to create session: connectionpool: unable to load X509 key pair: open : no such file or directory
```

Can someone explain why it works with ycqlsh and not from the application and also what changes I'd need to make to establish the connection from the app.

Comment: Can you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970581/ssl-options-in-gocql ?

Comment: Yes I did refer to the same but the issue is that when CaPath is specified ServerName has to be specified and I don't have the serverName and I am not sure where to find.

Comment: Can you check docs ? "ServerName must match the hostname in the server's certificate"